# How to get Buyer payment verification using paypal in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am new to PayPal integration in Asp.Net.

How to get Buyers Payment Detail by sending transaction ID to PayPal? I have received amount in my PayPal account but as the page was not redirected I am unable show payment details to buyer. Now i want to email payment details of the buyer by sending transaction ID to PayPal.
Is there any method for receiving buyer payment details with the help of transaction ID or some other means?

Help Appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetTransactionDetails](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails) method

Comment: How to implement this method?